# Redirect search to home page

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, search

I have a custom search bar which works fine on my Wordpress home page, however when I place it on a different page of the site, the URL keeps directing to `http://localhost/pageName/?s=searchTerm` instead of `http://localhost/?s=searchTerm`. I've tried setting form action to

```
<form method="get" id="searchform"  action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
```

and also hardcoding my site URL but the redirect happens every time.

Here is my searchform.php file:

```
<form method="get" id="searchform"  action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<div>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" />
</div>
</form>
```

How would I get the form to direct to `http://localhost/?s=searchTerm`?

Comment: Does action="/<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>"> work?

Comment: @Chris no the same problem happens

Comment: is this all codes in your searchfrom.php

Comment: @kashalo yes that's all the code that I have

Comment: try to add submit button and see if you issue is gone

Comment: @kashalo i tried but it still doesnt work unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

Just write

```
<form method="get" id="searchform"  action="/">
```

Comment: the problem is still there unfortunately

Comment: Running your code in my own Wordpress-installations it works as intended. A search thru the form returns me to mydomain.com/?s=searchterm. You must have some other issue connected to this. Have you checked your settings for home url? What does the function esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) return when you execute the code? What does the markup say thru view source etc.

Comment: yes, i checked my settings and the home url is correct. the function esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) returns the correct url and the view source action for the form also returns the same thing. not sure how else to troubleshoot

Comment: Unfortunately it's very hard to help you troubleshoot without more information. If the site uses pushstate it can mess your results up... but as we don't have access to your code it's very hard to know. We will keep asking question in the dark...

On last thing you could try is to reset your permalink settings and then revert to what you had before resetting.